# Is there any function called after the OnInitDialog function in MFC?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, dialog

I want to create a thread after the creation of a dialog box in MFC. Is there any function that Windows has provided and is automatically called after `OnInitDialog` so that I can create my thread inside it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply create your thread in the `OnInitDialog` function. There's no reason to overcomplicate things by going and searching for a different function, or splitting your initialization code up in two pieces. (There also *isn't* any such function, because there's no corresponding Windows message that is sent.)

If you want to get your dialog box on the screen *before* you create the thread, you can just show it manually using the [`ShowWindow` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72szh9c7.aspx). For example:

```
ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
RedrawWindow();
```

Also see this post by Raymond Chen: [Waiting until the dialog box is displayed before doing something](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/25/770536.aspx)

Comment: I found I also needed to call `CenterWindow()` because calling ShowWindow resulted in the dialog in the upper left.

Comment: @klox Hmm, that should not be necessary. Dialogs are automatically centered on their owner windows. This happens in an internal MFC function, `_AfxPostInitDialog`, which runs after `OnInitDialog`. `_AfxPostInitDialog` actually calls `CenterWindow` if the `OnInitDialog` function did not change the dialog's coordinates. But calling it explicitly won't hurt, either, so whatever works. Just make sure that you are centering it in a reasonable location, taking into consideration multi-monitor systems. Always centering on the primary display would be the wrong decision. :-)

Comment: I don't have an owner window (the dialog is the only window), but your description helps explain the change in behavior I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

`OnInitDialog()` is the main function called upon initialization (in reaction to `WM_CREATE`).

Why can't you create your thread in there?

Comment: i am creating two thread inside onintidialog function but when i run that then dialog box is comming very slowly.so i am creating thread inside ontimer i.e after 5 ms time when dialog formed then thread will start that is working fine. so i was thinking thatinstead of creating thread in timer if there is any other function which called after dialo is create then i can put my code there.is there any function exist?

Comment: Isn't `OnInitDialog` called in reaction to `WM_INITDIALOG`?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the thread priority to below normal and when the thread executes for the first time I set the thread to normal priory. This works fine. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

After many years of feeling unsatisifed with the OnTimer solution to draw first view graphics in an MFC dialog app (a favorite playground), this seemed like a nice simple solution:-

1. Add a WM_HSCROLL handler with class wizard.
2. At the end of OnInitDialog post a hscroll message with a NULL LPARAM
3. In handler detect the NULL, draw graphics.

a timer meant that the app was alive for some time before graphics happened, and apparently hscroll is prioritized to happen just after the WM_PAINT message which would erase a picture element to its blank state, deleting anything that was drawn during initdialog.

```
BOOL CSpecDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    ...

    PostMessage(WM_HSCROLL,0, (LPARAM)NULL);
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CSpecDlg::OnHScroll(UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar* pScrollBar)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    if (pScrollBar==NULL)
    {
        plot();
    }
    CDialogEx::OnHScroll(nSBCode, nPos, pScrollBar);
}
```